# How to restrict async_trait function's return value to implement Sync?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I'm using the `async_trait` crate to define an `async` method on a trait. I intend to transform the `Future` it returns into a `Stream`, wrap the `Stream` in an `Arc` and send the `Arc` over to multiple threads. Minimal reproducible code is as follows:

```rust
use async_trait::async_trait;
use futures::stream::{unfold, Stream};
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

#[async_trait]
trait Trait: Send + Sync {
    async fn do_something(&self) -> i32;
}

async fn use_trait<T: Trait>(x: &T) {
    let boxed: Arc<Box<dyn Stream<Item = i32> + Send + Sync>>;
    let lazy_poller = unfold(None, move |state| async move {
        if let Some(value) = state {
            Some((value, Some(value)))
        } else {
            let value = x.do_something().await;
            Some((value, Some(value)))
        }
    });
    boxed = Arc::new(Box::new(lazy_poller));
    let boxed_clone = boxed.clone();
    let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
    rt.block_on(async {
        let _moved = boxed_clone;
        // Do something with `_moved.next()`
    });
}
```

However it compiled with the following error:

```
error: future cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:21:22
   |
21 |     boxed = Arc::new(Box::new(lazy_poller));
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Sync`
   |
   = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `dyn futures::Future<Output = i32> + std::marker::Send`
note: future is not `Sync` as it awaits another future which is not `Sync`
  --> src/main.rs:17:25
   |
17 |             let value = x.do_something().await;
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ await occurs here on type `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = i32> + std::marker::Send>>`, which is not `Sync`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Stream<Item = i32> + Sync + std::marker::Send`
```

It seems that `async_trait` desugars the async methods' return types as `Pin<Box<dyn Future<...> + Send>>`, without specifying `Sync`. However I thought it would also be fairly common to require `Future`s to be `Sync`, in addition to `Send`.

My questions are:

- How should I specify the async method's return type to be `Sync`, and
- Why does `async_trait` **not** specify `Sync` for the return types automatically?

Comment: Your questions can be answered  as;  you cannot  specify  concrete `Future` type that is  returned from `async fn` as `Sync` . `Sync` is not implemented for this concrete type default or automatically, because single thread should be enough for polling since Futures shouldn't block, they should only watch as their nature. However in some cases you may need to poll futures from multiple threads, then you can use `shared()` from `FutureExt`(dependency: futures-rs).

Comment: For your actual code; I didn't get the requirement, if you explain why you are trying this, maybe you might get a better suggestion

Comment: @ÖmerErden Yes, I found it as well. `FutureExt::shared` is exactly what I need, and I did not need to transfrom it into a `Stream`

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, `Future`s do not need to be `Sync` for most of the use cases; and when it may be polled from different tasks, [`FutureExt::shared`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.12/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.shared) is the way to go, which is exactly what I needed for my use case. I did not have to transform it into a `Stream`.

As for my example, it would be:

```rust
use async_trait::async_trait;
use futures::future::FutureExt;
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

#[async_trait]
trait Trait: Send + Sync {
    async fn do_something(&self) -> i32;
}

async fn use_trait<T: Trait>(x: &T) {
    let shared = x.do_something().shared();
    let shared_clone = shared.clone();
    let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
    rt.block_on(async {
        let _moved = shared_clone;
        // Do something with `_moved.await`
    });
    println!("{}", shared.await)
}
```